# How to share internet connection on Windows network with static adresses?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet

I have a network where one computer is connected to the Internet with a modem. At the moment, it shares internet connection with the rest of the network the standard way (using ICS).

As a result it issues adresses dynamically, and clients' adresses keep getting changed.

For convenience, i need some machines on the net have static adresses. I would like them to be always issued those adresses (based on their MAC adresses). However, as far as i am aware, ICS does not support that.

What should i set up and configure to achieve that?

P.S. At the moment i have tried installing simple dhcp server (from [here](http://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/)), however: while i do get static adresses i wanted, i do not get a connection to the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assign a static IP address to an ICS client? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/648588/how-do-i-assign-a-static-ip-address-to-an-ics-client)

Comment: I have read that question before asking mine. If anything, i am alright with turning Windows' ICS off completely and sharing connection some another way.

Comment: Something like [AnalogX Proxy](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/proxy/Freeware.htm) (supports Windows 7) might help. I was using it a long time back during Vista days. Although it might work, better option would be to invest in a home router that does all the job for you.